# Need to store a PHP session variable when a link is clicked

Tags: php, html, session

In my code I have a link:

```
 <a href='http://www.anotherpageinmywebsite.com'>Click for the other page</a>
```

When the user clicks this link I need to save a value into a PHP session variable.  I don't want to use Ajax, nor an iframe, nor a GET variable (I don't want the session variable appearing to the user as it is *sensitive data*), EDIT nor do I want to put all the links on the page inside a form.

It seems like it *should* be possible -- because after all, clicking the link generates a call to the web server to load the new page, and shouldn't I be able to add some code (somehow) to "piggyback" on the natural process a link goes through to post a 'load this new web page' request to the web server?

How can I 'piggyback' on this naturally-occurring sequence of events when the user clicks a link to update a PHP session variable (without using GET variable,  ajax or an iframe, preferably).

Comment: @rid it's accessible in javascript before the link is clicked.

Comment: It's an ecommerce site but we do not have an SSL certificate.  The requirement I'm working under is "no GET variables".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to utilize the default behavior of the browser when a user clicks a link which calls back to the web server -- I wanted to 'piggyback' on that default behavior and send an updated session variable.  I was trying to avoid an extra call to the server to update my session variable and I was under the requirement "no GET variables are allowed."

In the end we punted and we coded an Ajax call to set the session variable.  We were not able to figure out how to 'piggyback' onto the default behavior of clicking the link without using a GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that you're using some PHP based framework and you have a controller which serves the pages according to URL - it's quite trivial in fact.

Assuming you are using CodeIgniter - but the logic would be the same for most MVCs out there.

```
<?php

class Web extends Controller {

  // this will fire when you access http://mysite.com/mypage
  function mypage($encoded_value) {
    $decoded_value = decode($encoded_value);

    // although CI has a different way of doing this
    $_SESSION['mypagesessionvar'] = $decoded_value; 

    $this->load->view('mypage'); // this loads the actual page
  }

}
```

Comment: Based upon the question, and a mention of being sensitive, and on the fact that we have to assume what is being used on the server - I would say that value for this variable should be somewhere on the backend and related to actual link that could be clicked. A lot of assumptions, yes.

One way I would try to solve this (if it has to come from frontend somehow) is that I would have another parameter which would in fact be encoded in some way. Then that paremeter would be used in the controller's function and given to session variable (decoded first of course).

Comment: This is straight php, javascript, html -- no libraries, not jquery, just php, javascript and html.

Comment: Well, then I would recommend doing it the same way but with straight PHP and encoded GET parameter (I know you said no GET but I don't see an alternative). Then you have your PHP for the page and simply get the value via $_GET['value'], decode it and store it in $_SESSION for later usage.